# pyspark json string to array type

Tags: pyspark

I'm working on a dataframe which contains a column that is a json array, which looks like this:

```
| col1 |                               col2                                    |
| ---- | --------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| aaaa | {"k1":"v1", "k2":{"k3":"v3"}},{"k1":"v2", "k2":{"k3":"v4"}}           |
| bbbb | {"k11":"v11", "k21":{"k31":"v31"}},{"k11":"v21", "k21":{"k31":"v41"}} |
```

col2 here is a nested json array string, my goal is to convert col2 from string to array so I can use explode function in pyspark to col2 to get:

```
| col1 |             col2                   |
| ---- | ---------------------------------- |
| aaaa | {"k1":"v1", "k2":{"k3":"v3"}}      |
| aaaa | {"k1":"v2", "k2":{"k3":"v4"}}      |
| bbbb | {"k11":"v11", "k21":{"k31":"v31"}} |
| bbbb | {"k11":"v21", "k21":{"k31":"v41"}} |
```

been stuck for a while, any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('col2', f.split(f.col('col2'), '\},\{'))
    .withColumn('col2', f.expr('transform(col2, (element, idx) -> case when idx = 0 then concat(element, "}") else concat("{", element) end)'))
    .withColumn('col2', f.explode(f.col('col2')))
)
```